# Debian 8 looping to the login mask despite password is correct

Tags: debian, login

I had a working installation of Debian 8 (64-bit), but the disk utility warned that the disk was almost full.

I deleted some very large files, but could not remove them from the Trash can.

Then, I tried emptying the Trash can from the terminal, using the "rm" command: https://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal

I cannot remember well if this succeeded, but I believe the disk utility was not updated after this attempt and still showed that the disk was full.
I had to stop the computer abruptly.

After a few restarts, I could see the login screen again.
The login seems working, but just after about one second redirects to the login mask again.

What should I do in such situation?

Comment: Use some rescue system on USB key, or boot single user with `init=/bin/bash` at GRUB time

Comment: _What_ very large files?

Comment: Looks like you deleted some configuration files, and when debian does not allow you to delete the files, take the hint, they are owned by root and probably are configuration files.

Comment: Switch to a text console (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`) and try to login there. What happens? If you get in, post the output of the following commands: `df -h`, `ls -l .xsession*`, `cat .xsession-errors` (can be long).